# PigLatin : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: mapreduce, weka, apache-pig

I'm very new to Pig Latin, trying to understand Pig Latin, with my homework, which I previously did with Map Reduce. And I'm getting GC overhead error, PS: my input is just 10 line simple csv file.

I'm trying to convert csv format to arff.

**My UDF:**

```
public class CSV2ARFF extends EvalFunc<String> {
private String arffDataString;
private String arffHeaderString;

public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
    if (input == null || input.size() == 0)
        return null;
    try{
            System.out.println(">>> " + input.get(0).toString());
            // csv to instances
            ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(input.get(0).toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
            CSVLoader loader = new CSVLoader();             
            loader.setSource(inputStream);
            Instances data = loader.getDataSet(); //**Line #30**
            //convert into arff
            ArffSaver arff = new ArffSaver();               
            arff.setInstances(data);                
            this.arffDataString = arff.getInstances().toString();               
            Instances arffdata = arff.getInstances();
            // header
            Instances header = new Instances(arffdata, 0);
            this.arffHeaderString = header.toString();
            this.arffDataString = this.arffDataString.substring(this.arffHeaderString.length());

            return arffDataString;

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("CSV2ARFF: failed to proces input; error - " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

**My script.pig**

```
REGISTER ./csv2arff.jar;
REGISTER ./weka.jar;

csvraw = LOAD 'sample' USING PigStorage('\n') as (c);

arffraws = FOREACH csvraw GENERATE pighw2java.CSV2ARFF(c);

--output

STORE arffraws INTO 'output' using PigStorage();
```

**Error**

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at java.nio.CharBuffer.wrap(CharBuffer.java:369)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:310)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)
at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:175)
at java.io.StreamTokenizer.read(StreamTokenizer.java:500)
at java.io.StreamTokenizer.nextToken(StreamTokenizer.java:544)
at weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.getToken(ConverterUtils.java:888)
at weka.core.converters.CSVLoader.readHeader(CSVLoader.java:937)
at weka.core.converters.CSVLoader.readStructure(CSVLoader.java:578)
at weka.core.converters.CSVLoader.getStructure(CSVLoader.java:563)
at weka.core.converters.CSVLoader.getDataSet(CSVLoader.java:596)
at pighw2java.CSV2ARFF.exec(CSV2ARFF.java:30)
at pighw2java.CSV2ARFF.exec(CSV2ARFF.java:1)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pig JVM java heap space error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822213/pig-jvm-java-heap-space-error)

Comment: @AndrewFinnell I already saw that post before posting my question, and tried pig -Dpig.mapred.child.java.opts=-Xms2048M script1.pig
but same error with 1024 and 2048 both

Comment: Does the process run longer after setting it to 2048? It is also possible the top level java process is running out of memory? Can you increase the Xmx size of the parent process not just the pig child.

Comment: @AndrewFinnell I think yes its running longer .. not sure! But how to increase Xmx size of top level java process?

Answer (score 0):

I had come across a similar situation.
Running the pig in local mode caused this error (pig -x local).
When i ran the same query in the Map reduce mode, then it got resolved (pig).

Hope it helps.